# gtkmm button coloring

Tags: c++, button, colors, background, gtkmm

I'm trying to change the background color of a button upon clicking it. I've connected the button to a clicking method just fine, but I can't seem to find the correct c++ syntax to create this. I've seen it done in python, but that doesn't exactly help me. Anyone have a tutorial or know the syntax?

EDIT: That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buttons don't have color, they contain a child object and emit a signal when pressed, that's it.

You are likely putting a Label in the Button as the child object.  A Label is text rendered by Pango, which lets you set attributes.  What you think is the Button color is actually the background color of the Label text.

Gtk is pretty complex, but lets you do anything.  If you want to do much with Gtk, look for a tutorial on Pango (text) and Cairo (images).  If you want a simpler self-contained widget set, check out wx or tk.